# f:viewParam (UIViewParameter) and immediate attribute

Tags: jsf-2

I have a page intended to edit some fields of a persistent entity. The page takes a GET request parameter which is a persistent id of my entity.

```
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="streamid" value="#{editStreamController.stream}"
            converter="#{editStreamController.streamConverter}" />
    </f:metadata>
```

A converter is used to convert id to an entity by loading it from a persistence service as described e.g. [in here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ConvertingAndValidatingGETRequestParameters).

The page contains a form used to edit some fields of the '*stream*' entity. I an using OmniFaces `<o:form includeViewParams="true">` in order to enable inclusion of my GET parameter in the `action` string of the form:

```
<o:form includeViewParams="true" >
...
    <h:inputText id="name" value="#{editStreamController.stream.name}" >
        <f:validator binding="#{editStreamController.validator}" />
    </h:inputText>
...
```

In some situations it happens that when the form is posted, both `f:viewParam` responsible for the entity AND `h:inputText`s dealing with the entity's fields must pass decoding, validation and model update phases, so that the entity is made available first, and then its fields are updated. It would be quite natural for me [to set `immediate="true"`](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#WhenShouldIUseTheImmediateAttribute) for `f:viewParam` in order to set its value first, and thus to later avoid null pointer issues for UIInputs with values like `"#{editStreamController.stream.name}"`. However according to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewParameter.html#isImmediate%28%29), the `immediate` setting is not relevant to `UIViewParameter`.

So why is the `immediate` setting not configurable for `UIViewParameter` and is there a workaround for such a situation? Thanks a lot in advance!